# Significance of $1 + 2 + 3 . . . +2n$ within inductive proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, induction

I am going through the third edition of Spivak's *Calculus*, and an element of an induction problem is leaving me with great confusion.

The problem in question is the second problem of Chapter 2, part (i), which asks one to find a formula for $$\sum_{i = 1}^n (2i-1)= 1+3+5\;.\;.\;.+(2n-1)$$

The solution to this problem is eventually $n^2$, I do not know *why*. The hint given asks what this expression has to do with $1+2+3\;.\;.\;.+2n$. My questions are these:

Why does this statement matter to the problem? Additionally, how can the expression be true if it contains odd numbers when it should only produce even ones?

Thank you in advance for any solutions.

Comment: You know that $$1+2+3+\cdots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\Rightarrow 1+2+3+\cdots+2n=\frac{2n(2n+1)}{2}$$. But $$1+2+\cdots+2n=(1+3+5+\cdots+(2n-1))+2(1+2+\cdots+n) $$

Comment: Note that $1+2+3+4+\dots+(2n-1)+2n = (1+3+5+\dots+(2n-1))+(2+4+6+\dots+2n)=(1+3+\dots+(2n-1))+2(1+2+3+\dots+n)$.  Expression on the furthest left should be known, as should the parenthetical expression on the far right.

Comment: To me, the first part might have used induction to prove that $1+2+\cdots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, and the second part is just an application of the result obtained in the first part. The question you asked might have nothing to do with the induction. Although proving the result with induction is super easy.

Comment: @JMoravitz Alternatively, use $(2 + 4 + 6 + \cdots + 2n) = (1 + 3 + 5 + \cdots + (2n-1)) + n$

Comment: Thank you all for the insightful comments, I see where my approach was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint is implying you should start by considering $$1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + 2n = \left[ 1 + 3 + 5 + \cdots + (2n-1) \right] +  \underline{~~~~~~~~~~}$$

Where I assume you already know what the left side sums to

Comment: Clicked after reading this. Very much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

## Inductive Proof

$$1+2+3+\cdots+(2n-1)=n^2. \tag 1$$
Obviously, $(1)$ holds for $n=1$,which is trivial.

Let's make the inductive hypothesis as $(1)$ holds for $n=k$, namely, $$1+2+3+\cdots+(2k-1)=k^2.$$

Then, when $n=k+1$, we obtain 
\begin{align*}
1+2+3+\cdots+[2(k+1)-1]&=(1+2+3+\cdots+2k-1)+[2(k+1)-1]\\&=k^2+2k+1\\&=(k+1)^2.
\end{align*}

which shows that $(1)$ also holds for $n=k+1.$ By the induction principle, we are done.